# How to ng-repeat in array values in Views

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How to use ng-repeat on array values inside an ng-repeat in VIEWS?

My second ng-repeat doesn't work.

The value of generalDocument.documents is:

**["14-10-2015.xls","15-10-2015.xls","16-10-2015.xls"]**

```
 <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
        <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Branch</th>
            <th>Document Type</th>
            <th>Desciption</th>
            <th>Reference Number</th>
            <th>Issue Date</th>
            <th>Expiry Date</th>
            <th>Documents</th>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat="generalDocument in generalDocuments | orderBy: 'generalDocument.id' | filter: search">
            <td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ generalDocument.company.company_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ generalDocument.branch.branch_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ generalDocument.document_type.document_type }}</td>
            <td>{{ generalDocument.description }}</td>
            <td>{{ generalDocument.reference_number }}</td>
            <td>{{ generalDocument.issue_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ generalDocument.expiry_date }}</td>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default  btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                     Download <span class="caret"></span>
                  </button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li ng-repeat="document in generalDocument.documents track by $index">
                      <a href="">{{ document }}</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
```

UPDATE: 
I added **track by $index** and now it loops. But loops per character.

UPDATE:
I console.log generalDocument and generalDocument.document is fetched from database as

```
document: "["EK 845 FDX 20150906 00001 CARGO1.xls","EK 845 FDX 20150906 00004 MOH.xls","EK 847 FDX 20150811 000010 COMMPERSONAL3.xls"]"
```

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't work"? what does it do? can you create an example jsfiddle/plunker to demonstrate?

Comment: The second ng-repeat doesn't even loop. I'm suspecting maybe there is something wrong with my array in **generalDocument.documents**

Comment: do you see an error message in the console?

Comment: weird, at first I didn't see any error. haha

but now there is: **Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed.**

Comment: It sounds like the value of `generalDocument.documents` might be a string, not an array? It would really help if you reproduce it in a jsfiddle/plunker as yarons suggested. I created a pared down one here and it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/qc0pL6g4/

Comment: @sheilak I guess your right. It shows as string in console log.

document: "["EK 845 FDX 20150906 00001 CARGO1.xls","EK 845 FDX 20150906 00004 MOH.xls","EK 847 FDX 20150811 000010 COMMPERSONAL3.xls"]"

Comment: @sheilak How can I fix this is view?

Comment: @yarons he is right. generalDocument.documents is fetched from database as string. how can I fix this in view?

Comment: That string is valid JSON so you can use JSON.parse() to convert it into an array https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: @sheilak thanks for the help. I just changed my model from the server so it will return json array instead of string value. now the ng-repeat works as it should. Thak you all for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure you have an array in the "documents" property? It looks like a string in the UPDATE you posted.

"JSON.parse" it first if it's coming as a string from the server. And ideally you should change your server response to send the array instead.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I am pasting an example. please include angular.min.js

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Angular JS Directives</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="contrl">
            <p><input type="text" ng-model="city" /></p>
            <p>My City Name is: {{city}}</p>
            <p><input type="number" ng-model="qnty" /></p>
            <p><input type="number" ng-model="cost" /></p>
            <p>Total amount is : {{(qnty * cost)|currency}}</p>
            <p><input type="text" ng-model="test" /></p>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="x in names | filter:test | orderBy:'country'">
                    {{(x.name | uppercase) + ',' + x.country}}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script>
            angular.module('myApp', []).controller('contrl', function ($scope) {
                $scope.qnty = 1;
                $scope.cost = 5;
                $scope.names = [
                    {name: 'Jani', country: 'Norway'},
                    {name: 'Hege', country: 'Sweden'},
                    {name: 'Kai', country: 'Denmark'}];
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Yusuf. The example you posted doesn't look similar to my case. The code I have has two ng-repeat.

In my code, the first ng-repeat works. The second ng-repeat does not which has Array values instead of Json objects.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the help.

generalDocument.document is fetched from database as STRING.

I just changed my model from the server so it will return json array instead of string value. now the ng-repeat works as it should.